# OneDrive as disk in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, onedrive

My goal is to setup a music library with ability to stream that music. I store music on my local PC and it is synced with OneDrive. I tried to search for a way to get the links of those files on OneDrive and use those links to actually play the files (and gather tags if possible). But from what I understand if I am to use JS FilePicker all users accessing the site will have to authorise and thus they will be getting list of *their* files, instead of *my* files. So, in my understanding I can't create a *publically* accessible music library using JS FilePicker.

Thus I started thinking of Azure. Is it possible to mount OneDrive in Azure VM as if it's a mounted drive? So that I won't use extra space for storage, when I already have payed for it through OneDrive.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is very much the intended usage of OneDrive and Azure storage.

OneDrive is your personal service, not a cloud service you can use to create cloud apps and share it with others. It's quite typical that users have their Office documents or photos taken on a phone stored in there. You do not want to grant access to your OneDrive for others.

On the other hand Azure Storage is meant to be a cloud service. Designed to be scalable, flexible and to be shared among many users.
Storage space in Azure is extremely cheap so it won't cost you much to set up a storage for your files.